# Laravel redirection using withInput doesn't allow to change inputs values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is project from scratch, so if you want you can do exactly as I showed.

I created the following migration just to create users table and add new record:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 60)->unique();
        $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
        $table->string('password', 256);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::table('users')->insert(
        [
            [
                'name'     => 'admin',
                'email'    => 'admin@admin',
                'password' => Hash::make('password')
            ]
        ]
    );
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

My routes are:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'main_route',
    function () {
        return View::make('hello');
    }
]);

Route::post('/', [
    'as' => 'main_route',
    function () {
        if (!Auth::attempt(
            [
                'email'    => Input::get('email_to_fill'),
                'password' => Input::get('password_to_fill'),
            ]
        )
        ) {


        }

        return Redirect::route('main_route')->withInput();
    }
]);


Route::get('/logout', [
    'as' => 'logout',
    function () {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::route('main_route');
    }
]);
```

My `hello.blade.php` is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
@if (Auth::check())
    I'm logged in. E-mail {{ Auth::user()->email  }}

    <a href="{{ URL::route('logout') }}">Log out</a>

    {{Form::open(['url' => URL::route('main_route'), 'role' => 'form']) }}

    {{ Form::text('email', Auth::user()->email) }}


    {{Form::submit()}}
    {{Form::close() }}
@else
{{Form::open(['url' => URL::route('main_route'), 'role' => 'form']) }}

{{ Form::text('email', 'do not touch this') }}

{{ Form::text('email_to_fill', 'admin@admin') }}
{{ Form::text('password_to_fill', 'password') }}

{{Form::submit()}}
{{Form::close() }}
@endif
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing complicated so far.

So I open in my browser main page and click to send form (data is already filled in HTML so I don't need to fill in anything).

Below images:

[image: Page before sending form]

[image: Page after login]

After sending form I'm being logged in but as you see value of input is not correct. In code there is it should display in input value `Auth::user()->email` but it displays old value from `email` field before sending.

**Question**: Is it correct Laravel behaviour - when using `withInput` with redirect it will automatically fills all form inputs with the same values and even passing manual other value it will use the old data? Probably this example could be a bit simpler (without user login at all) but this is the exact problem I faced so I put it here as simple as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. I would post a more in-depth answer, but I can't think of any; that's just what it does :P

An example of why you might want this is if you're editing a record; it should load the record from the DB and populate the edit-form. Then you submit, and it turns out something failed validation. It should remember your posted data and prioritise it above the DB value so that you can change it.

The easiest fix would to to just not redirect `->withInput()` if the authentication was successful.

Comment: So it basically means when I have form I don't need to set value for any field when using withInput because Laravel will fill all of them automatically? And if for example for one field I would like to set other value I would need to either change this input name or don't use withInput method or use Input::except? I wasted about 6 hours to narrow my problem to above code because I thought there is rather problem with `Auth` here and not only forms.

Comment: Yep - I'd personally use `Input::except` if you really need to, but you could also do something like pipe it on through an interstitial controller action (eg. `/login` POSTs to `/login/process` which then forwards on to `/dashboard` when logged in). This way you can redirect `->withInput()` on failure, but without it on success

Comment: In fact this is much more complex form where there are many fields and if user is not logged he can fill in fields to be logged in and I wanted to display his userdata if he resend the form and some of other data are not valid. Now I know I can for example change those 2 input names and solve it other way. Thank you