# Blade Templating Input Type Value

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade, hidden-field

In Html forms i can do this as like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
```

I would like to do this in full blade templating like this :

```
{{ Form::hidden('token', $token, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

But the second option doesn't pass the `$token` value. Where do i go wrong ?

-- UPDATE --

**I have found the solution for this :**

It is quite easy question, but had to be careful while naming the inputs in blade templating.

This is my first form, which is working nice :

```
<form action="{{ action('RemindersController@postReset') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
    Email<input type="email" name="email">
    Password<input type="password" name="password">
    Password<input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</form>
```

**In blade templating form it was like **

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'RemindersController@postReset')) }}
   {{ Form::hidden('token', $token , array('class' => 'form-control')) }} 
   {{ Form::email('email', null, array('class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Mail address')) }}
   {{ Form::password('pass', array('class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'New Password')) }}
   {{ Form::password('pass_conf', array('class'=>'form-control input-sm','placeholder'=>'Confirm Password')) }}
   {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-info btn-block')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**--SOLUTION--**

**So the error is :**

In 1st form,

```
Password<input type="password" name="password">
Password<input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
```

In 2nd form,

```
{{ Form::password('pass', array('class'=>'form-control
input-sm','placeholder'=>'New Password')) }} 
{{Form::password('pass_conf', array('class'=>'form-control
input-sm','placeholder'=>'Confirm Password')) }}
```

input names are **password** and **password_confirmation**, and in the second form they are named **pass** and **pass_conf**.

I changed pass to password and pass_conf to password_confirmation and it's now working fine.

Thank you for your feedbacks and patience.

Comment: My guess is that your `$token` variable is null

Comment: I can pass the value in first type of form. But in second, i can't. If it was null, i couldn't be able to pass the value in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess but you can try to put also static value:

```
{{ Form::hidden('token', 'some token here', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

and now check if it is in page source.

If it's not it means that you probably redirect to form using `withInput` and then Larravel fills the form with the same data as previous even if you set value manually to any HTML form element.

In this case you could make redirection using:

```
->withInput(Input::except('token'));
```

If it's the case you can read more about it in this topic: [Laravel redirection using withInput doesn't allow to change inputs values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933629/laravel-bug-or-feature-form-with-redirect-shows-old-value)

**EDIT**

You should try to change:

```
return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
```

into:

```
return Redirect::back()->with(array ('error', 'token'), array(Lang::get($response), Input::get('token'));
```

Comment: i put the token value statically something like '5aee974a557c3568d93645529220eb27642e566a' and it appears in the page source.

Comment: Yes, when i put token outside with {{ $token }} it displays the value what i wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marcin for spending your time, but the error's solution was quite easy, i updated my post. Again, thank you for sharing your experience.